# Require the user to enter the server's superuser/root password in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, root

I'm making a system called NCIV in PHP. In that system you can change a setting in settings.php, which allows the system's admin to enable or disable the usage of MySQL rather then a bunch of text files.
However, changing that setting if the site already has content, will move all the data from/to the MySQL Database to/from the text-file based database (according to the setting's value). This is the code:

```
/*******************************************************/
/* __          __     _____  _   _ _____ _   _  _____  */
/* \ \        / /\   |  __ \| \ | |_   _| \ | |/ ____| */
/*  \ \  /\  / /  \  | |__) |  \| | | | |  \| | |  __  */
/*   \ \/  \/ / /\ \ |  _  /| . ` | | | | . ` | | |_ | */
/*    \  /\  / ____ \| | \ \| |\  |_| |_| |\  | |__| | */
/*     \/  \/_/    \_\_|  \_\_| \_|_____|_| \_|\_____| */
/*                                                     */
/*    CHANGING ["server"]["mysql"] WHILE THE SITE IS   */
/*      ALREADY IN USE WILL MIGRATE ALL DATA TO THE    */
/*               MySQL DATABASE IF TRUE                */
/*        OR TO THE TEXTUAL DATABASE IF FALSE!!        */
/*                                                     */
/* IF YOU HAVE A HUGE SITE, THIS CAN TAKE A FEW HOURS  */
/*              OR EVEN A FEW DAYS OR WEEKS!!          */
/*       PLEASE ONLY CHANGE THIS SETTING IF YOU HAVE   */
/*                 JUST INSTALLED NCIV!                */
/*                                                     */
/*                                                     */
/*                                                     */
/*   REMOVING OR MODIFYING THIS WARNING WILL TAKE THE  */
/*                   ENTIRE SITE OFFLINE!              */
/*                                                     */
/*               YOU WILL NEED TO ENTER THE            */
/*   SERVER'S SUPERUSER/ROOT PASSWORD AFTER CHANGING   */
/*                      THIS SETTING!                  */
/*                                                     */
/*        NEVER TRY TO MIGRATE THE DATA MANUALLY!      */
/*******************************************************/
$GLOBALS["NCIV"]["server"]["mysql"] = FALSE;                        //Enable MySQL? See the WARNING above!
```

Is there a way to check if the user entered the correct superuser/root password in PHP after the setting has changed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's always [PAM](http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM)... but this is a very, *very*, **very** bad idea.

Also, keep in mind things like, say, shared hosting, where the user won't have root.

If this setting is so dangerous, perhaps you should reconsider it even being a setting to begin with.

Comment: Thanks! I'll change it so that the user must enter the admin password. This feature is required for compatibility.

Comment: I assume you're moving the data storage from old flat files to the new MySQL database?  If so, perhaps instead of (just) a setting, you should build an external or otherwise not-automatic conversion script, so that there's not a high chance of someone accidentally shooting themselves in the foot.